# Powershell and Exchange - Set SMTP Primary address

Tags: powershell, smtp, exchange-server

I'm in an hybrid environement with Exchange 2016 and Office 365.
I wish to script the process to enable a Remote Mailbox, an change the primary SMTP address of a user.

By example, I have a user who Remote Mailbox has been enabled. He has a SMTP primary address like this: User1@My-Group.com

With the command below, I can change the SMTP primary address just fine:

```
#Disable Email Address Policy
Set-RemoteMailbox User1 -EmailAddressPolicyEnabled $false

#Change SMTP address
Set-RemoteMailbox User1 -PrimarySmtpAddress "User1@My-good-address.com"
```

Everything is just fine, when I go to my On Premise Exchange 2016, I can see my user1 addresses like that:
SMTP:User1@My-good-address.com
smtp:User1@My-Group.com
...

But, when I put back Email Address Policy to $True, I have this result on Exchange:
SMTP:User1@My-Group.com
smtp:User1@My-good-address.com
...

That doesn't happen when I do the change manually.

Does anyone know why I have this behavior?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved...
I was just on the ONLY USER who was missing an attribute, and the wrong email policy was applied.